# How do I scroll a RichTextBox to the bottom?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, richtextbox

I need to be able to scroll a RichTextBox to the bottom, even when I am not appending text. I know I can append text, and then use that to set the selection start. However I want to ensure it is at the bottom for visual reasons, so I am not adding any text.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You could try setting the SelectionStart property to the length of the text and then call the ScrollToCaret method.

```
richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Not very reliable, I am afraid. You sometimes get scrolled just so the top pixel of the caret is visible.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013 and WPF, but ScrollToCaret() method does not exist for RichTextBox , Any Idea?

Comment: @gatopeich - put a newline at the end of your text and you should be able to see everything

Answer (score 18):

The `RichTextBox` will stay scrolled to the end if it has focus and you use `AppendText` to add the information. If you set `HideSelection` to false it will keep its selection when it loses focus and stay auto-scrolled.

I designed a Log Viewer GUI that used the method below. It used up to a full core keeping up. Getting rid of this code and setting `HideSelection` to false got the CPU usage down to 1-2%.

```
//Don't use this!
richTextBox.AppendText(text);  
richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
```

Answer (score 14):

In WPF you can use ScrollToEnd:

```
richTextBox.AppendText(text);  
richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
```

Comment: the question is about winforms, scroll to end doesnt exist there

Answer (score 0):

Code should be written in the rich text box's TextChanged event  like :

```
private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
       richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```