# How can i make that the richTextBox scroll the text up instead the bars?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I scroll a RichTextBox to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895470/how-do-i-scroll-a-richtextbox-to-the-bottom)

I did in the constructor:

```
richTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both;
```

But when the text that start from the top getting down i need to drag the bars down to see the text. Instead how can i make that the text will push the bars down so if i want to see the upper/old text i will need to drag the bars up ? So all the time i will the next/new text that coming from the bottom.

```
private void init()
        {
            cancel = false;
            currentCrawlingSite = new List<string>();
            sitesToCrawl = new List<string>();
            richTextBox1.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Alvin the link you gave is not working. At least for me.

Comment: Are you calling it every time you append content to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<=RichTextBox1.Text.Length;i++)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = i
```

Comment: Codelgnoto sorry your code is not working either.

Answer (score -1):

The solution i found is :

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

To put it in a TextChanged event.
Now its working perfect.

Thank you all.